# How to display error on top of page instead of displaying beside input html element

Tags: html, angularjs

How to display error on top of page instead of display errors beside input html element. Please suggest.

```
<ng-form name="frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance">
            <div style="padding-bottom: 8px;">
                <button id="cm-SaveBtn" name="cm-SaveBtn" type="button" ng-click="submitted=true">Save</button>
                <button id="cm-RefreshBtn" name="cm-RefreshBtn" type="button">Refresh</button>
            </div>
          <div>
                    <table>

                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="VNAVLabel">Process Begin Date: </span></td>
                            <td> 
                                <span><input type="date" name="processBeginDate" ng-model="processBeginDate" required></span>
                                <span ng-show="(frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance.processBeginDate.$dirty || submitted) && frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance.processBeginDate.$error.required">
                                    Process Begin Date is required
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>

</ng-form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all the form's errors in `form.$error`.

Simply iterate on the errors and show wherever you want. Like:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, errors) in form.$error track by $index">{{ key }} errors :
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="error in errors">{{ error.$name }}-{{ key }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please remove ` <span ng-show="(frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance.processBeginDate.$dirty || submitted) && frmdisbursementScheduleMaintenance.processBeginDate.$error.required">
                                    Process Begin Date is required
                                </span>` and add the <ul>...</ul> at top. Hope it helps

Comment: then please elaborate more, as your question says top of page, so I hope all the errors within the <form> tag or outside top of form tag?

Comment: Currently I am printing errors beside html input element. I want to print below my buttons. Let's say for now I just have one input element. If I have 3-4 input elements I want to show all those errors below my buttons inside of beside html input elements

Comment: Thank You @anoop. But I want to display those messages only on save button click. Can you help to update

Comment: Great. Thanks @Anoop